# SherlockAction Bar theme like Instgram ?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I was using the Instagram Android application. A screen shot can be found here [here](http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/04/Screenshot_2012-04-03-09-33-01.png). If you notice the left hand corner contains a back arrow and then a divider. The name of the screen is next to it, but is not clickable. I have integrated the ActionBarSerlock in my project. How can i achieve this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: That looks like a custom implementation, and not abs.

Comment: Ignore the other icons. I just want to know basically how the back button and a divider can be placed in the left hand corner ?